# im trying to make a age and name approval. When they have 0 chances they cant continue. My problem is when they get 0 they can still continue

Tags: python

```
password = "12345"
for i in range(4):
    pwd = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD : ")
    j = 3
    if(pwd == password):
        print("WELCOME!")
        break
    else:
        print("Not Valid, try again and chances left are",j-i)
        continue
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when they run out of chances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue even if it reaches 0 chance. Instead of using for loop use while loop instead. So until the requirements meet, it's don't stop.

```
    password = "12345"
while True:
    pwd = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD : ")
    j = 3
    if(pwd == password):
        print("WELCOME!")
        break
    else:
        print("Not Valid, try again")
        continue
```

with nested if to restart every time it reach zero

```
        password = "12345"
chances = 4
    while True:
        pwd = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD : ")
        j = 3
        if(pwd == password):
            print("WELCOME!")
            break
        else:
            print("Not Valid, try again")
            chances -= 1
            if(chances <= -1):
              print("Your chance depleted pls restart again")
              #restart chance
              chances += 4
            continue
```

output

[image]

Comment: but like i want it to have chances lets say they get it wrong, i want it to say chances left : 2. Until 0 then they have to restart

Comment: You can use nested if. To count chances if reach zero implement break so the while loop stop or to restart

Comment: do you mind giving me the example? like writing it out

Comment: Look to my answer again I edit it and add a nested if.

Comment: for some reason it says the while True doesnt exist on my coding thing

Comment: Can i see the error?

Comment: It's impossible you might miss-line your code to your IDE.

Comment: password = "12345"
chances = 4
    while True:
        pwd = input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD : ")
        j = 3
        if(pwd == password):
            print("WELCOME!")
            break
        else:
            print("Not Valid, try again"):
            chances -= 1
            if(chances <= 0):
              print("Your chance depleted pls restart again")
              #restart chance
              chances += 4
            continue

Comment: while True:  (unexpected indent)

Comment: That's actually weird mine works fine.

Comment: should i type it out or copy paste cuz what i did is copy paste

Comment: Try copying my code, I add an image of the output of the code.

Comment: it worked thanks so much! there is another favour if you dont mind. is there a way to add a chances left? in the output. e.g. Chance left: 3/2/1/0

Comment: Yes of course. use this  `print(f"Not Valid, try again. Chances left {chances}")`

Comment: where to put that?

Comment: To "Not valid" print. from else.

Comment: for some reason it says depleted when it only hits one chance how do i do it until chances 0?

Comment: My apologize haha. Instead `if(chances <= 0):` use this `if(chances <= -1):` this should fix the problem.

Comment: thank you so much bro you're the best. I tried asking so many people and they couldnt help like u. ur a hero bro!

Comment: Glad to hear that, Good luck to your coding journey brother.